# Checking two values throws error when value is two digits and single digits using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I am trying to check two conditions: if `second` value is less than or equal to `first` then `true` else throws errors and if `first` value is not there then the second value should be `read-only` like below snippet. But when I enter two digits `eg: 12` in the first number and single digits `eg: 4` in second numbers, then `alert` is popped up saying `errors`. Where did I do wrong?

```js
$(document).on('change', '.first, .second', calculate);

function calculate() {
  var first = $('.first').val();
  var second = $('.second').val();
  //alert([first, second]);
  
  if (first != '') {
    $('.second').prop('readonly',false);
  } else {
      $('.second').prop('readonly',true);
  }
  
  if (second > first) {
    alert('Second value should be less than or equal to first value');
    $('.second').val(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>First</label><br>
<input type="number" min="0" class="first" id="first">
<br>
<br>
<label>Second</label><br>
<input type="number" min="0" readonly class="second" id="second">
```

If I enter single digits at both then errors are not there, play the above snippet and you'll understand the problem.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're comparing strings, not integers. Use `parseInt()` to convert them

Comment: inputs are treated as strings and not integers as far as i know...

Comment: Your snippet is working properly.

Comment: I used parseInt() then it's working fine, didn't know that input are treated as strings, thanks all

Comment: @Chaska no it's not. Enter `12` in the first box and `4` in the second

Comment: but my other condition, to put `readonly` or not is now not working :)